# Android enable warning for custom library if new version is available

Tags: android, version, android-library, android-lint

With the support libraries, for example, Android Lint will show a warning if the library is not using the latest version. However, when I created my own library and published it through Bintray, no warning is displayed when using an older version. Is there any way to enable this behavior for custom libraries as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the following in your Android Studio.

> Settings > Editor > Inspections > "Newer Library Versions Available"

This will introduce a lint check on your gradle dependencies. But, remember this may slowdown your compile time. Another alternative is,

> Analyze > "Run Inspection By Name" > "Newer Library Versions Available"